# Solving an irregular recursive sequence?

Tags: math, recursion, binary, sequence

I was playing around with some number sequence ideas earlier and came up with something which I'm unable to solve myself (although I've only worked on it an hour or so...).  Looking for any inspiration or a closed form solution to this problem!

Here's the idea; for an index n, the binary representation of n gives the indexes of several other elements in the list; the sum of these elements is the value for index n.  The initial two elements are both 1, and numbers and indexes in binary representation are 1-indexed, not 0-indexed.

So for example, the third element has index 3, so the binary representation is 11; this means that the third element should be sum of elements 1 and 2.  Therefore, the third element has value 2.  Similarly, the fourth element has binary index 100, so it is just the third element, which means it has a value of 2 as well.

Computing the first few numbers, I got the sequence:

```
1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, ...
```

The binary representation part gave me an idea for a recursive formula:

```
floor(log_2(n)) = k (just getting max of k where 2^k <= n)
a_n = a_k + a_(n-k)
```

This is just taking off the first 1 from the binary representation and separating the sum into two parts: the highest-index element and the rest of the elements.  We also define a_0 = 0 here, for completeness' sake.  This means that, for example, the 4th through 7th elements are simply just a_2 added to a_0 through a_3.

Been working on this for a while now, and I haven't been able to progress beyond this.  Does anyone have any ideas for this?

Edit: Sorry about the 1-indexing!  I debated between 0-indexing this and 1-indexing it, but I think 0-indexing it actually changes the sequence and makes the math much more complex.  If anyone has any suggestions for the 0-index version, let me know!  The sequence would then be

```
1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, ... (starting from index 0)
```

Comment: For the 0-indexed: if n = Sum(b_i * 2^i) then a_n = Sum(b_i * a_i); if n = s+t where s&t=0 then a_n = a_s + a_t.  Not sure if this is helpful or not. Interesting problem!

Comment: One thing is clear `a_{2k+1} = a_{2k} + 1`. However, even indexes are harder...

Comment: shouldn't the zero-indexed sequence start with 0 rather than 1? if so, a clear 4-per-group repeating pattern emerges

Comment: That trivializes it, I'm interested in when the 0-indexed sequence starts with a 1.  Thanks for pointing that out though!

Answer (score 1):

[OEIS](http://oeis.org/) is a marvelous tool for this kind of thing.  It tells us that your 0-indexed sequence is the [base 2 digital convolution sequence](http://oeis.org/A033922).  Maybe this gives you a starting point.